Vote option says I can't vote to close after retracting my vote, but I didn't retract my vote
I voted to close this question because it's not about programming.
It was re-opened.
The question is still not about programming and I would like to vote to close it, but when I try, it says "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote".  But I never retracted my vote.

Is the message incorrect or is this a bug?

I think this is a bug, or at least it should be; the wording in the past was "You have already voted to close this question", if I recall correctly. The current wording is unclear.

You participated in closing the question when it was asked (nearly a week ago), and since then it has been reopened. The system counts this as "retracting" your vote for you: you don't get to vote to close it again.
I think there's legitimate discussion to be had around whether this system is a good idea. In general, the question could be quite different from how it was when closed; on the other hand, it could be substantially the same and the reopening might have been entirely misguided.
But the purpose seems clear: to avoid having two warring factions of users repeatedly re-open and re-close the same question due to their disagreement.

Shouldn't the message say something to the effect that I can't vote to close because I previously voted and it was re-opened?  Or...my vote "was retracted" when it was re-opened?  The way the message reads right now makes it sound like I'm the one who retracted my vote and that's confusing.

...I agree, having run into it many times myself. I'm not sure the database tracks the information that would be needed to make that distinction.

Side question:  does this mean those who voted to re-open are not eligible to vote to re-open the question again if it's closed again?  Or is the disenfranchisement one-sided?

@devlincarnate you get one close and one reopen vote per post unless you're a moderator.
